# SVN commit all unmerged revisions from branch to trunk

Tags: svn, merge, branch, branching-and-merging

While developers are committing `branch` bugfixes, they may immediately merge **some** back to `trunk`. However at some point, it's my responsibility to make sure **all** branch commits have been merged back to `trunk`.

I know I can use the following command to get unmerged revisions:
`svn mergeinfo branch trunk --show-revs eligible`

But then what is the command to merge just those revision back to `trunk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ordinary `svn merge` (1-st form from `svn help merge`): if you use `svn mergeinfo` command, then existing SVN has merge-tracking support and one of it's advantages is: merged revisions will not be re-merged again

I.e (just for sample) if branch `SOMEBRANCH` contains revisions 10-20 and 11,13,15,17 was cherry-picked earlier into trunk

`svn merge ^/branches/SOMEBRANCH`

will merge **all** rest revisions (10,12,14,16,18,19,20) **without** previously merged